# Ubuntu MATE and ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion

I'm just asking ... If  I switch to Ubuntu MATE and if I ask something here the solution will be the same?Could I ask here questions if I switch to Ubuntu MATE? (My English is very bad sorry)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Ask Ubuntu Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help) (which I think you were prompted to look at when you signed up **;-)** ), the following distributions are considered official Ubuntu flavors:

- Kubuntu
- Lubuntu
- Ubuntu Budgie
- Ubuntu Kylin
- Ubuntu MATE
- Ubuntu Studio
- Xubuntu

All of these are on-topic. Honestly, there isn't much difference among these. It's mostly just the desktop environment, themes and certain pre-installed packages.

Since Ask Ubuntu tends to reflect the list of official flavors on the Ubuntu website, you may also want to look there. Chances are, if a new official flavor is named, Ask Ubuntu won't have it immediately.

#### Reference

- https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors

Comment: The same list of flavours on the official Ubuntu WIki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors

Comment: Oh thank you so much :).I'm thinking to change Ubuntu Mate.But I don't know yet.I can't decide.

Comment: @ByteCommander I know that :p. I just figured it would be safer to only list what AskUbuntu told me. I'll add that in though.

Comment: @ThetisClena It's mostly preference. MATE is a replica of GNOME 2.x, which is what Ubuntu looked like up until 2010. It's a little confusing at first, but you can have a lot of fun with all the panels and customization.

Comment: @Zacharee1 that's why i'm thinking to switch Mate :D

Comment: @ThetisClena Do it! Try it out, and if you don't like it, you can either reinstall normal Ubuntu or install Unity on top of MATE if you have the space.

Comment: @Zacharee1 :D okay I'll make it.But I guess tomorrow It's late in Turkey.I'm about to sleep.But thank you :) I'll change to Ubuntu Mate tomorrow. :3

Comment: @Zacharee1 I'm now using Ubuntu MATE and it's awesome.Thank you and other people for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

The only differnce between {L|X|K|Ed}Ubuntu {Mate|Gnome} is the desktop and preinstalled software. Nearly everthing should work on all Ubuntus

Comment: Thank you ^^.I love ask Ubuntu.You people are nice.

Comment: +1 for ` {L|X|K|Ed}Ubuntu {Mate|Gnome}`   :)

Comment: @CarlH :) , but it is a little bit wrong. In correct EBNF it should be `Name="Ubuntu", ("Mate"|"Gnome"|"Server"|"Kylin"|"Studio"|"Touch"|"Snappy Core") | ("L"|"X"|"K"|"Ed"), "ubuntu" | "Mythbuntu"`